# Does endianness affect the values in a character array?

Tags: arrays, char, endianness

I have an IPv6 address stored as a 16 byte character array.
uchar ip6[16];
I have to check that whether it is a multicast address or an unicast address. The known way is to check the first byte which if has a value of "FF" will imply that it is a Multicast address. Now I wanted to know does endianness affect the storage of a character array.

Comment: We'd have to see the code. Most likely, no. But you never know. The character array might contain the address in host byte order.

Comment: No. `char` is not affected by Endianness, as `sizeof(char) == 1` on any platform.

Comment: @barakmanos `char j[4]; int32_t i=1; memcpy(&j, &i, 4);` -- Still think the contents of that character array doesn't depend on endianness?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: No, but you have added `int i` "to the equation". OP states `uchar ip6[16]` in his/her question!!!

Comment: @barakmanos I have `char j[4];` in mine. It could just as well be `uchar ip6[16]`. The answer completely depends on how his array is populated. (The OP says nothing about how his array is populated, which is what we need to know. We have no idea what else is in the OP's equation.)

Comment: Doesn't this depend on your programming language? Which one are you using?

Comment: I am getting IPv6 header from the packet and then I am getting the address from that. This address is stored in a character array.
ip6_info = header->ipv6;
ip6_info is a structure which stores v6 addresses in char arrays of char ip6_addr[16]
Now, if I check ip6_addr[0] then due to endianness am I not supposed to always get the first element of the array stored at the 0th index of array

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. The code you described never converts the addresses to host byte order. So the host's byte order does not affect the contents of the array.